# reboot windows (with password) using subprocess.call in python

Tags: python

The following code can reboot the windows, however how can I automatically provide the windows password during rebooting?

```
import os, subprocess

subprocess.call(['shutdown', '-r'])
```

Comment: When you say automatically provide the windows password, do you mean that you want to log the user back into the machine?

Comment: Pretty sure for security reasons you... can't.

Comment: I'm not sure that he can't, but I don't think it would be a good idea. He could probably setup a mouse/keyboard event provider that could click in the right places and press the right keys, but it wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: @CrazyCasta yes, exactly i want to log the user back into the machine providing the user password previously in the script

Comment: @mhlester i do not think it is related to security issues, since the user just automate the process providing the password in the script.

Comment: @viena What you have just described IS a security problem. One should NEVER store a password on a system in a form that the system can determine the password without extra information (like an encryption key).